# where is credential cached for Microsoft HPC

Tags: credentials, hpc

when using the following command :
cluscfg setcreds [/scheduler:] [/user:\]

where is the credential cached? On the machine where this command is run? or 
on the scheduler machine?

Also, when does this cache expire? It stays as long as the account password has not expired?

Answer (score 0):

I checked with one of the MS HPC techs and according to him

> For this case, the credentials will be cached on the scheduler or head node and it won’t expire until the password expires on the AD.

Answer (score 0):

This document has a very good explanation of what happens with the credentials. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6873 under Security Considerations for Jobs and Task (page 33) [image]